# Richtextbox disable unrenderable characters

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a C# WinForms app with a `RichTextBox`. This textbox will contain a string generated randomly of all Unicode characters (or at least as many as possible). Problem is, that it can't display some characters. When I check in VS using breakpoints etc., the characters are correct, so it is just a display problem - see picture. Is there any way either to make the textbox display these characters correctly, or filter these in the code not to even be generated?

Here is the code I am using for the generation (for now generating all, later it will be a random number)

```
        string key = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
        {
                key += (char)i;    
        }
```

And here is the image how it then looks in the textbox:
[image]

Comment: [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18043/Removing-or-replacing-non-printable-Unicode-charac), is exactly exactly what you need, hope this will help you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those empty squares are actually [control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) (and other) characters that can't really be displayed in a meaningful way like letters and numbers, such as `null` character, tab, "end of transmission", etc...

You could restrict your results to [printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) by using a few methods on in the `Char` class:

```
string key = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
{
    var c = (char)i;
    if (Char.IsPunctuation(c) || Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        key += c;
}
```

It's not perfect. There are still some unprintable characters, but far less than your screen shot.

I'd probably try to avoid all those string concatenations too. The following will create an array of characters and then just create one string, instead of creating `"length"` number of strings.

```
var key = new string(Enumerable.Range(1, length)
                               .Select(i => (char)i)
                               .Where(c => Char.IsPunctuation(c)
                                           || Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                               .ToArray());
```